# Publish from Visual Studio to secured cluster error

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, visual-studio-2015, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

I've created secured Service Fabric cluster on Azure like described in [Create a Service Fabric cluster by using Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm) and use self signed certificate as cluster certificate and AAD.  (CN in certificate different from actual cluster URL, if it important)

Now I can connect to cluster through Cluster Explorer and PowerShell, but I can't publish application through Visual Studio, checkmark for endpoint in 
publish dialog always red and then I try to publish I get SignIn error saying "AADSTS90002: No service namespace named '...' was found in the data store. " and don't ask for credentials

Comment: Looking very strange. Full error description:
"AADSTS90002: No service namespace named **'2c327be8-e30c-4'** was found in the data store."
It's look like some part of GUID was lost in some way, because it's just a part of it.

Comment: We have seen this issue as well, it started appearing some time ago and I had a hard time nailing down the exct circumstances. What worked for me (after a lot of retrying, using bad words, restarting VS, Windows, reinstalling tooling etc.) was: clear out the certificates information in the publish profile. Save. Quit VS. Open VS. Edit publish profile (add cluster thumb + admin cert thumb/loc). Open publish dialogue. Don't know why it happened, only that it started happening without any apparent change on our side.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate CN must match the cluster dns name. Otherwise you'll get problems when authenticating.
Since it's a self signed one, it should be easy to make a correct cert and try again.

(Don't use self signed certs for production scenarios though. It's unsafe.)

Comment: It does't matter what CN i use, correct or incorrect, I always have the same error

Comment: if the cert is now correct, check if your service principal is created correctly (rights, scope)

Comment: Sry, but how and where I can do it ?

Comment: easiest is to use 'SetupApplications.ps1' from 'MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric-AADHelpers.zip' like described on your linked page. On the Azure Portal, under App Registrations, there should be a native app. It should have 2 API's with delegated permissions: Access **_Cluster and Windows Azure AD.  Test code to see if principal can authenticate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth

Comment: I used 'SetupApplications.ps1' from linked page and it's looking like all permissions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with Visual Studio tools for Service Fabric and not any error on the user side. We (Microsoft) have a fix that should hit the net in the next tooling release, and we believe it should address this problem, but we had trouble reproducing the issue in-house. If you @Dimitry Bolshakov have some time to help us with debugging, please send me an email (karolz at you-know-where), it would be much appreciated.

UPDATE 3/1/2017: Thanks to a friendly user (Peter) we now have a repro and a fix. The fix is scheduled to go into 5.5 release of Service Fabric SDK and tooling, to be released sometime later this month.

Unfortunately we do not have a good workaround for the current release of the tooling, other than using PowerShell for publishing the application outside of VS.